# Why would a blocking socket repeatedly return 0-length data?

Tags: c++, c, networking, network-programming, sockets

I'm having a significant problem using a standard BSD-style socket in a C++ program. In the code below, I connect to a local web server, send a request, and simply create a loop waiting for data to return. I actually *do* receive the data, but then I get an endless stream of 0-length data as if it was a non-blocking socket. The web server presumably didn't kill the connection, because if so I would have received a length of -1.

Please ignore simple typos I make below, as I'm writing the code from memory, not a direct copy/paste. The code produces the same result on OSX and Windows.

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//assume serv_addr has been created correctly
connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0);

std::string header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: 127.0.0.1:80\r\n"
    "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n"
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

send(sock, header.c_str(), header.length()+1, 0);

for (;;) {
    char buffer[1024];
    int len = recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0);
    cout << len << endl;
    //this outputs two numbers around 200 and 500,
    //which are the header and html, and then it
    //outputs and endless stream of 0's
}
```

Comment: No, recv will only return -1 if you have an error on the client side. If the server disconnects from you, you will get a 0, which is basically like an EOF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man page of recv

```
For TCP sockets, the return value 0 means the peer has closed its half
     side of the connection.
```

Comment: When recv() returns 0, the connection was closed; but if you want to poll (or wait on) the socket for incoming data, check out the man page for select().

Comment: Wow thanks, I guess that was a misunderstand on my part, but why would it close the connection if I specified "keep-alive"?

Comment: `Connection: keep-alive` is just a suggestion; an HTTP/1.1 server does not have to honor it, and an older server won't even know what it means.  But more importantly, a properly defensive client is *always* prepared for the server to disconnect, regardless of whether the protocol allows it to do that at that point in the state machine.